# Data not reflected in SQL SERVER management studio

Tags: sql-server

I have this issue in SQL SERVER 15.0, in SQL have various ways to access to DB using IP, using Hostname, using (local) or just dot (.)

When access to SQL management studio or using a SQL in my code using and IP to access to server I receive a query result with 60.300 lines and when access using just dot for example I receive 149 more lines. But when I execute again query in IP connection I receive now same number of lines in dot.

I can't find solution for this, its some type of cache from SQL? Dot (.) is more fast than IP? or some configuration I have?

Comment: If you are getting different results you are either connecting to a different instance, or the data differs. I suspect you are connecting to different instances.

Comment: No I didn't I checked and IP is the same of (local)

Comment: Then you would get the same result sets, the data has been changed between running the same statements, or the permissions you have a different, if you are certain, that the instance is the same. What does `SELECT @@SERVERNAME;` return on the 2 instances? If it's the same, then one of the above statements will be true.

Comment: Server name is same I checked before asking, instance is same, I used SA for connect to both with password (not windows authentication). A note SQL is changed to a SSD disk a few weeks ago. Can be the issue?

Comment: *"Server name is same I checked before asking,"* then *something* is different, however, we don't know what as we don't have enough information.

Answer (score -1):

When connecting to SQL server instance, using any of these means "connect to local default instance of SQL Server", that is the instance on the machine where Management Studio (client) is running.

- LOCALHOST
- 127.0.0.1
- . (dot)
- (Local)

If you do not want to connect to the local copy of SQL, you should provide the remote server DNS name or IP address.

To complicate things a bit more, SQL server has a concept of a named instance, so you can have multiple instances of SQL server running on the same host computer. These are referred to by specifying a named instance name after the server name.

For example: `192.168.0.1\NamedInstance`

To resolve your issue, make sure you are connecting to the correct instance. If you are connecting to the same instance and getting different results, it could be a timing issue.

Comment: Yes, I know about instances and like i said in other comment IP is same of (local) or dot. I checked twice before asking. Can you tell me more about timming issue?!

Comment: If I understand correctly you ran it fron your app and got 60,300 records. Then you ran it in SSMS and got 60,449 records. Then you ran it in the app and got 60,449 records. Is it possible that 149 records were inserted between the first and second run?

Comment: Hi, nop impossible i take 5 minutes or more to open management studio etc... But this happens a lot of times.

Comment: Check transaction isolation level. If one connection is using nolock to do dirty reads, it will see data before it is committed. Compare set options two connections are using in profiler